# Assigning a list during recursive function in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need help with assigning lists in a recursive function. How can I assign a value to the i<sup>th</sup> member of a list when the recursive function is in i<sup>th</sup> iteration?

Comment: you'll need to pass it as function argument

Comment: Do you need something like we made in, for example, Haskell? Can you be more clear in your question? I don't think recursion is popular in Python word (specially when we talk about lists).

Answer (score 0):

You can't change an iterable while using it to drive an iteration, but you could easily make an iterable to hold your results and pass it in to the recursive function as an argument:

```
results = []

def recurse(level, results):
   level += 1
   results.append(level)
   if level < 10: recurse(level, results)

print recurse(0, results)
>>> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

but in this example you could **not** do

```
for item in results:
    recurse (item, results)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm understanding well your question, but I think it's something like:

```
# put "s" on 2nd position of the list ['l', 'u', 'c', 'a', 's']
# so the result should be ['l', 's', 'c', 'a', 's']
```

If so, keep in mind that there are better ways to do it in Python. So here's the code:

```
def assign_in_position(elem, my_list, pos):
    first = my_list[0]
    tail = my_list[1:]

    if pos == 0:
        return [elem] + tail

    return [first] + assign_in_position(elem, tail, pos-1)
```

If you're new in Python there's only one thing that can be strange (slicing, `my_list[1:]`). This function is also kind of buggy, but it's proposital. It works for my first example, but if you're learning recursion, then you should learn how to detect and solve common recursion problems.

Out of curiosity, this is the Haskell code for the same task:

```
assign_in_pos elem [] _ = [elem]
assign_in_pos elem (_:t) 0 = elem:t
assign_in_pos elem (h:t) pos = h:assign_in_pos elem t (pos-1)
```